# SKSpriteNode - how to change the tap / hold point of the node

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, skspritenode

Lets say i have some long object, lets say this arrow here:

[image: example arrow]

Right now, if i want to drag and move the arrow, when i tap and move it - its being held from the centre.

I want the tap and hold point to be its tail. I tried to search for a fitting property (such as anchorPoint), or physicsBody properties, but i didn't find anything that seemed to work.

Does anyone know a solution to my problem? Thank you!

Comment: try: anchorPoint = {1, 0.5}

Comment: this worked but didnt work well with my other calculations. what i did eventually was to DOUBLE to length of the arrow, while keeping his original size in half, and other half was empty, which resulted in the 'center' of the sprite being the back end of the arrow :)